# Windows 10 associated my .sh files to Notepad

Tags: windows, sh

Accidentally, Windows 10 associate my .sh files to Notepad and I cannot make it run in command prompt. Now it opens in Notepad. How can I change it? Whne a file extension is associated with some program, Windows allows to change, bt not to delete association, and there is no way to associate .sh files to command prompt

Answer (score 3):

For my installation of Windows 10, .sh files are associated with Git Bash, not command prompt.

You say you associated .sh files with Notepad by accident, but you didn't say that you ever associated .sh files with command prompt, so maybe you made a false assumption that they were previously associated with command prompt.

If that's correct, then to re-associate the file with Bash, right click on a .sh file, click **open with**, click the **Always use this app to open .sh files** at the bottom, then click **Git for Windows** in the list.

Comment: I do not have Git for windows. No options appear to me in my PC

Comment: If you press the windows key and type bash, nothing comes up? How were you running .sh files in command prompt before? With cygwin or something?

Comment: It is the fist time I do it. I am learning MongoDB and I dowloaden a .sh file I was trying to run. Maybe mingw  would run it?